# Error after adding sheets into xlsx file using pandas and openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

After adding some sheets to workbook and saving it, I'm facing issue when try to open the result file  "We found a problem with some content in filename.xlsx ..."

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = '123.xlsx'

book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1], [1]], columns=['a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2], [2]], columns=['b'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[3], [3]], columns=['c'])

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='x123')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='x124')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='x324')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Can you add the full error text to your question?

Comment: This could be anything. You'll need to provide a sample file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.